# Using a dockerfile argument in a RUN statement

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile, which works:

```
FROM someimage
ARG transform

COPY Web*.config /inetpub/wwwroot/
RUN powershell /Build/Transform.ps1 -xml "/inetpub/wwwroot/web.config" -xdt "/inetpub/wwwroot/web.debug.config"
```

However, I'd like to make the `web.debug.config` file an argument passed in when I build.  So I've changed the last line to:

```
RUN powershell /Build/Transform.ps1 -xml "/inetpub/wwwroot/web.config" -xdt "/inetpub/wwwroot/${transform}"
```

When I do this, the `${transform}` argument does not get interpolated and gets converted to an empty string.  I've confirmed that the `transform` argument is getting passed in correctly, since I can do:

```
COPY ${transform} /inetpub/wwwroot/
```

...and the file gets copied.  Is there some other way of interpolating arguments in a string using the RUN command?

I'm using Docker 18.03.1-ce on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found a solution that works but it's definitely not ideal.  It appears variables simply aren't expanded in RUN statements (at least on Windows, haven't tried Linux).  However, the COPY statement will expand them.  So, I can copy my file to a temp file with a hard coded name, and then use that:

```
COPY ./ /inetpub/wwwroot/
COPY ${transform} /inetpub/wwwroot/Web.Current.config
RUN powershell -executionpolicy bypass /Build/Transform.ps1 -xml "/inetpub/wwwroot/web.config" -xdt "/inetpub/wwwroot/Web.Current.config"
```

In this particular situation, it works for me.

**Update: Found another method that works**

This is perhaps a better method using environment variables:

```
FROM someimage
ARG transform
ENV TransformFile ${transform}

COPY ./ /inetpub/wwwroot/
RUN powershell -executionpolicy bypass /Build/Transform.ps1 -xml "/inetpub/wwwroot/web.config" -xdt "/inetpub/wwwroot/$ENV:TransformFile"
```

In this case, Docker will evaluate the parameter `transform` and set it to the environment variable `TransformFile`.  When I use it in the PowerShell script, it's no longer Docker that's evaluating the argument, but Powershell itself.  Thus, the Powershell syntax for interpolating an environment variable must be used.

Comment: Can confirm that they aren't expanded on Linux

Answer (score 0):

The [shell form of Dockerfile RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) should allow for arg expansion.

Check if the quotes are not in the way with

```
RUN powershell ... -xdt "/inetpub/wwwroot/"${transform}
```

Note: you can see in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile#powershell-in-dockerfile) powershell commands using `$var` instead of `${var}`

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, that didn't work.  I tried both `"/inetpub/wwwroot/"${transform}` and `"/inetpub/wwwroot/"$transform`

Answer (score 0):

Try this dockerfile

```
FROM someimage
ENV trans transform

COPY ${trans}/inetpub/wwwroot/
RUN powershell /Build/Transform.ps1 -xml "/inetpub/wwwroot/web.config" -xdt "/inetpub/wwwroot/${trans}"
```

Run the command

```
docker build --build-arg transform="web.debug.config" -t sample:latest .
```

Comment: Yea, I went down that route too.  Environment variables are evaluated by the shell at runtime, so it's not really a templating mechanism.

Comment: Try below docker file                                                                    FROM someimage 
ARG transform
ENV trans transform
COPY ${trans}/inetpub/wwwroot/ 
RUN powershell /Build/Transform.ps1 -xml "/inetpub/wwwroot/web.config" -xdt "/inetpub/wwwroot/${trans}"           Run "docker build --build-arg transform="web.debug.config" -t sample:latest ."

Comment: Same thing.  I get: `Step 5/5 : RUN powershell -executionpolicy bypass /Build/Transform.ps1 -xml "/inetpub/wwwroot/web.config" -xdt "/inetpub/wwwroot/${trans}"
 ---> Running in 16042f7076ad
Transforming /inetpub/wwwroot/web.config using /inetpub/wwwroot/
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find a
part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\'."`